# Replace values in a dataframe, until it matches a given value

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, subset

I have hundreds of dataframes withi the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(yr=seq(0,20,1), op=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

I would like to automatically replace the initial part of the column`op` as the sequence would continue from the end of the vector, but just until the second `0` value.

It should result like this:

```
df.result <- data.frame(yr=seq(0,20,1), op=c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

It must be dynamics, because the sequences are all different.
Any tips for doing this quickly with a function without needs for loops?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean given a dataframe d and a vector v you need to replace the first v.length elements of d with a ?

Comment: I mean that I need to replace the first elements of the second column of my dataframe with the continuation of its sequence, until it reaches the second zero. No other vectors are involved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
transform(df, op = replace(op, cumsum(!op) < 2, seq(which(!op)[2] - 1) + tail(op, 1)))
```